# JBOSS AS7.2 startup issues: Doesnot delpoy?

Tags: java, jboss, netbeans-7

I am able to start up the server JBOSS EAP 6.1.0  and clean build the Java packg, but I am not able to deploy..I am getting this error: please help me how to resolve this..
thnaks in advance!

---

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "plant.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.plant.plant.env.glossaryDS is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.jdbc.glossaryDS]"],
    "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => [
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.AttributeTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.ConverterTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.ValidatorTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"managed-bean.us.mn.state.dot.plant.handler.DataScrollerListHandler\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"managed-bean.us.mn.state.dot.plant.handler.PlantDetailHandler\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"managed-bean.us.mn.state.dot.plant.handler.PlantIndexHandler\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"managed-bean.us.mn.state.dot.plant.handler.PlantSearchHandler\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.component.html.util.ExtensionsFilter\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.AliasBeanTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.AliasBeansScopeTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.buffer.BufferTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.calendar.HtmlInputCalendarTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.checkbox.HtmlCheckboxTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.collapsiblepanel.HtmlCollapsiblePanelTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.collapsiblepanel.HtmlHeaderLinkTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.column.HtmlColumnTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.creditcardvalidator.ValidateCreditCardTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.crosstable.HtmlColumnsTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.datalist.HtmlDataListTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.datascroller.HtmlDataScrollerTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.date.HtmlInputDateTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.div.DivTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.document.DocumentBodyTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.document.DocumentHeadTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.document.DocumentTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.dojo.DojoInitializerTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.emailvalidator.ValidateEmailTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.equalvalidator.ValidateEqualTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.HtmlInputFileUploadTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.htmlTag.HtmlTagTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.inputHtml.InputHtmlTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.inputTextHelp.HtmlInputTextHelpTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.jslistener.JsValueChangeListenerTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.jsvalueset.HtmlJsValueSetTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.layout.HtmlPanelLayoutTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.navigation.HtmlCommandNavigationTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.navigation.HtmlPanelNavigationTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.navmenu.HtmlNavigationMenuItemTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.navmenu.HtmlNavigationMenuItemsTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.navmenu.htmlnavmenu.HtmlCommandNavigationItemTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.navmenu.htmlnavmenu.HtmlPanelNavigationMenuTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.navmenu.jscookmenu.HtmlJSCookMenuTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.newspaper.HtmlNewspaperTableTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.panelstack.PanelStackTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.popup.HtmlPopupTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.radio.HtmlRadioTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.regexprvalidator.ValidateRegExprTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.savestate.SaveStateTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.schedule.ScheduleTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.selectOneCountry.SelectOneCountryTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.selectOneLanguage.SelectOneLanguageTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.selectitems.SelectItemsTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.sortheader.HtmlCommandSortHeaderTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.stylesheet.StylesheetTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.swapimage.HtmlSwapImageTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.tabbedpane.HtmlPanelTabTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.tabbedpane.HtmlPanelTabbedPaneTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.tabbedpane.TabChangeListenerTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.tree.taglib.IconProviderTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.tree.taglib.TreeCheckboxTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.tree.taglib.TreeColumnTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.tree.taglib.TreeSelectionListenerTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.tree.taglib.TreeTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.tree2.TreeTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.custom.updateactionlistener.UpdateActionListenerTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ActionListenerTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ConvertDateTimeTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ConvertNumberTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.LoadBundleTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ParamTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.SelectItemTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.SelectItemsTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.SubviewTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ValidateDoubleRangeTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ValidateLengthTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ValidateLongRangeTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ValueChangeListenerTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.VerbatimTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ViewTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlColumnTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlCommandButtonTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlCommandLinkTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlDataTableTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlFormTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlGraphicImageTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlInputHiddenTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlInputSecretTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlInputTextTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlInputTextareaTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlMessageTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlMessagesTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlOutputFormatTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlOutputLabelTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlOutputLinkTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlOutputTextTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlPanelGridTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlPanelGroupTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlSelectBooleanCheckboxTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlSelectManyCheckboxTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlSelectManyListboxTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlSelectManyMenuTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlSelectOneListboxTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlSelectOneMenuTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.HtmlSelectOneRadioTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlCommandButtonTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlCommandLinkTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlDataTableTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlGraphicImageTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlInputHiddenTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlInputSecretTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlInputTextTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlInputTextareaTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlMessageTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlMessagesTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlOutputLabelTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlOutputTextTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlPanelGridTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlPanelGroupTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlSelectBooleanCheckboxTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlSelectManyCheckboxTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlSelectManyListboxTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlSelectManyMenuTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlSelectOneListboxTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlSelectOneMenuTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html.ext.HtmlSelectOneRadioTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.CatchTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ChooseTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.OtherwiseTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.RemoveTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ForEachTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.IfTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.SetTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.WhenTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ForEachTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ForTokensTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.IfTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ImportTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.OutTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ParamTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.RedirectTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.SetTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.UrlTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.WhenTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.BundleTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.FormatDateTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.FormatNumberTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.MessageTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParamTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseDateTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseNumberTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.RequestEncodingTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetBundleTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetLocaleTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetTimeZoneTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.TimeZoneTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.DateParamTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.ParamTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.QueryTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.SetDataSourceTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.TransactionTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.UpdateTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ExprTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ParamTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ParseTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.TransformTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForTokensTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ImportTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ParamTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.RedirectTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.SetTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.UrlTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.WhenTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.BundleTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.FormatDateTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.FormatNumberTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.MessageTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.ParamTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.ParseDateTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.ParseNumberTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.RequestEncodingTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.SetBundleTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.SetLocaleTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.SetTimeZoneTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.TimeZoneTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.DateParamTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.ParamTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.QueryTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.SetDataSourceTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.TransactionTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.UpdateTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ExprTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ParamTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ParseTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.TransformTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlFmtTLV\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlSqlTLV\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlXmlTLV\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"us.mn.state.dot.jsfcomponent.tag.DisplayComponentTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"us.mn.state.dot.plant.servlet.DataSheetGeneratorServlet\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"us.mn.state.dot.plant.servlet.PlantImageServlet\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"us.mn.state.dot.plant.servlet.PlantThumbnailImageServlet\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".component.\"us.mn.state.dot.plant.servlet.SearchResultReportServlet\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".deploymentCompleteService",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"plant.war\".jndiDependencyService",
            "jboss.web.deployment.default-host./plant"
        ],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle11g",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.jdbc.glossaryDS"
        ]
    }
}
15:48:58,234 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment plant.war (runtime-name: plant.war) in 288ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your data source glossaryDS before you try to deploy your application.

[Here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_BRMS_Platform/5/html/BRMS_Administrator_Guide/Configuring_a_Datasource_for_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_6.html) you have the Red Hat guide to configure it, change the driver according to your data base.